# Does `boost::make_tuple` make copies?

Tags: c++, boost-tuples

I have something like this in my code

```
val = boost::make_tuple(objA , objB);
```

My question is does `boost::make_tuple` make copies of objA and objB ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the returned object is a `boost::tuple<A, B>` which contains an `A` object and a `B` object, so they have to be copied from the arguments.

If you want a tuple of references, use [`boost::tie(objA, objB)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html#tiers) instead, which returns a `boost::tuple<A&, B&>`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you want to it hold references, use boost::ref (or cref for const references)...

```
boost::make_tuple(boost::cref(objA), boost::cref(objB));
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does. A tuple holds variables by value, so it must copy the values into the tuple. If you want only their references copied, use pointers instead, i.e., `boost::make_tuple(&objA,&objB)`.